# Using regexes to process HTML of a *known structure*

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, regex

We're using a custom framework built on top of ASP.NET MVC to generate HTML from our object models at runtime without writing any views. This approach has been successful in allowing rapid application development and maintaining a uniform look and feel across multiple applications.

For a couple of pages in our current application however, the framework has been generating extraneous h2 and h3 tags with no content, which will lead to the application failing QA testing.

The only viable long-term solution is to fix the framework. But we're supposed to go to QA in a couple days, and I'm tempted to just use a regex to strip out the offending tags from the rendered HTML.

I realize that this is a kludge, but is it viable as a short-term solution, until we figure out why the framework is misbehaving? Please note that my group (building the app) is not the same group that maintains the framework. The latter group might fix the issue tomorrow, or they might fix it in a month - I have no control over the timing.

A few considerations:

1. It is generally frowned upon to use regexes to process HTML. But while I understand that regexes are not adequate to handle the general case of parsing arbitrary HTML, is it really so problematic to use a regex to modify HTML whose exact structure is known in advance?
2. Given that this step will be carried out every time the page loads, will there likely be a significant performance cost to this? We're looking at stripping out two or three tags here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

1. no
2. keep in mind that your regex don't know that you have only 2 or 3 replacements in specifics places and will process all the html content. Keep in mind too that if you want remove something like `<h2></h2>` or `<h3></h3>` you don't need a regex and you can use a simple string replace. If you know where these tags are in the tree, you can easily use xpath or any DOM feature to find them and remove them. You must make tests to find the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Cheating on QA tests to HIDE the issues of ANOTHER group?
QA are exactly the thing that should find this sort of issues so that they are corrected.

On the other hand, having QA text empty tags is somewhat equally bad but lets ignore that for a bit:

1. If you know the exact thing to remove, regex is ok. With compiled regexes (that are simple and properly written), they behave as fast as simple string searches.
2. The performance hit is negligible. And its just so you pass that QA, right? ... right?

Comment: I wouldn't really say we're hiding it, we are logging it. Our manager asked if we could provide a workaround so that the project schedule doesn't slip over such a trivial issue. And yes QA is that fussy, empty headers will give the accessibility testers fits.